# Java - JSpitPane Anchor Right

Tags: java, user-interface, jsplitpane

Is there a way to anchor the divider of the JSplitPane to the right of the window?

[image]

This is my current my current window when I run the application. However, when I resize it, the divider remains on the location I set.

Like  this:
[image]

Is there a way to anchor it such that the right component will retain its size?

Here's my current code:

```
JSplitPane p = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
p.setLeftComponent(new JPanel());
p.setRightComponent(new JPanel());
p.setDividerLocation(500);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setResizeWeight to the required weight you need between 0 and 1. setResizedWeigth divides the amount of space taken on by each panel. e.g. if you set the weight to 0.5 then the panels will half the new free space, if you set it to 1 the right panel will stay the same size and the left panel will absorb all the new space. So an answer to your question if im reading correctly, just add this line of code

```
p.setResizeWeight(0.5);
```

Hope this helps.